# for loop only shows first item in array when trying to display in tableView

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to display tableview cells based on items in an array but for some strange reason it will only display the first item in the array.  When I use a print statement it shows the array it being iterated through correctly.

Here is the array:

```
 var restaurants = ["Truckyard", "EasySlider", "Revolver", "Armoury"]
```

Here is the cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = restaurantTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! restaurantCell

    for rest in restaurants {

      cell.restaurantImageView.image = UIImage(named: rest)
      cell.restaurantNameLabel.text = rest

    }

    return cell
  }
```

Comment: You are writing wrong.
How many Image view you have in your single cell?

Comment: You don't use a `for` loop in `cellForRowAt`. This function is called once per row. Use the `indexPath.row` to access the right element from the array

Answer (score 2):

cellForIndexPath is called once for each row. Try this instead:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = restaurantTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! restaurantCell

    cell.restaurantImageView.image = UIImage(named: restaurants[indexPath.row])
    cell.restaurantNameLabel.text = restaurants[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for a loop. cellForRowAt is providing you with an indexPath. Check the indexPath.row property. If you only have one section, the row is the index of the item in your array you want to access. You are basically iterating over your array for each row and this will inevitably set your last item as the title/image